# How to make sure that I can scroll up in AJAX chat

Tags: javascript, scroll, chat

I am building a **vanilla** JS, AJAX chat (so **no** jQuery or other toolkits). The messages are loaded via AJAX and put in a div that uses overflow-y: scroll; so you can scroll through all the messages.

Because the latest messages appear at the bottom I have a scrollDown() function that scrolls to the end of the div:

```
function scrollDown()
{
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("chatbox");
}
```

The problem is that I can't scroll up. If I do that I will get to the bottom again. This is because on every ajax call I scroll down. But how can I make sure that if an user is scrolled up in the div (so he/she is reading past messages) that it doesnt scroll down when AJAX gets updated.

I already tried some things with div.scrollHeight, div.scrollTop but unfortunately it didn't work. I also did a lot of Google searches but no luck either and most them were jQuery though. Here is my code;

```
<script type="text/javascript">


getBerichten();

function getHTTPObject(){
   if (window.ActiveXObject) return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) return new XMLHttpRequest();
   else {
      alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
      return null;
   }
}   

function doWork(id, user_id) {    
    nieuwbericht = getHTTPObject();
    if (nieuwbericht != null) {

        if( document.getElementById('bericht').value != "")
        {

        nieuwbericht.open("GET", "ajaxberichten.php?id=" + id + "&user_id=" + user_id + "&bericht="
                        + document.getElementById('bericht').value, true);

        nieuwbericht.send(null); 
        document.getElementById("bericht").value = "";
        }
    }
}

function setOutput()
{
    if(httpObject.readyState == 4){
        document.getElementById('berichten').innerHTML = httpObject.responseText;
        bericht = document.getElementById('chatbox');

        scrollDown();

        setInterval(getBerichten(),1000);


    }
}

function getBerichten()
{
    httpObject = getHTTPObject();

    if (httpObject != null) 
    {
        httpObject.open("GET", "ajaxgetberichten.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>", true);

        httpObject.send(null);
        httpObject.onreadystatechange = setOutput;
    }
}

function scrollDown()
{
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("chatbox");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
}


</script>


<div class="postbox">

    <div class="post">

        <div class="chatbox" id="chatbox">
            <div id="berichten"></div>
        </div>

        <form method="post" action="">
            <textarea name="bericht" id="bericht"rows="20" cols="85"> </textarea>
            <input name="verstuur" type="button" onclick="doWork(<?php echo $_GET["id"] ?>, <?php echo $user_id ?>);" value="Verstuur"/>
        </form>  

    </div>
</div>
```

Could somebody please tell me how to fix this without a JS toolkit like jQuery?

Thanks